# Update the selected dropdownlist value base on value from another linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I use the following code to get the LOV for dropdownlist and setting a selected value as well:

```
ViewData["dropDown_Color"] = correspondingDropDownValue
                                .Select(j => 
                                    new SelectListItem { 
                                            Text = j.ListOfValue, 
                                            Value = j.ListOfValue, 
                                            Selected = j.ListOfValue 
                                                            == x.DefaultValue 
                                            })
                                .ToList();
```

Now that I have a dropdownlist in my `ViewData`, I want to update the selected value of this `ViewData["dropDown_Color"]` base on the following query

```
var userPref = from m in db.UserColorPref
               where m.UserID.Equals(userSessionID)
               select m;
```

The value to be updated can be access by `userPref.color`. May I know how to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 List<SelectListItem> selectlist = ViewData["dropDown_Color"] as List<SelectListItem>;
            selectlist.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.Selected = x.Value == userPref.color;

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
ViewData["dropDown_Color"] = new SelectList(YourSelectList, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
```

Comment: Hi @Jatinpatil, correct me if i'm wrong, isnt that the new SelectList is adding a new item into the list? I'm not trying to adding a new item into the existing list, i just want to update the selectedValue from the existing list

Comment: No it will not add any new item in your select list.